# HDD recovery -- linux does not see drive (fdsik -l)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, data-recovery

`fdisk -l` does not see the HDD. The hdd is from a friend's lenovo laptop (ultrabook type). He says that the hdd made a clicking noise that went away the last time he tried booting his laptop. His bios fails to book the disk. My desktop does not see it in windows or linux with gparted, /media, or with fdisk.

That said, the disk does spin and I do not hear a clicking noise. I do not know how it failed, and I have physical access to the disk, but I wouldnt want to go as far as replace the circuitry on it.

Would spinrite work?

Or what would you recommend?

Comment: Can you see it in the BIOS?

Comment: gah! forgot to check! My friend took his harddrive home but Ill have access to it tomorrow most likely. What if I can see it in BIOS, what then?

Comment: Well, if it doesn't show up in the BIOS at all, then that is a problem - there's no way to recover any data at all using software if it's completely non-working (unless you want to try swapping boards, which is not all that likely to work even on a desktop drive where it's physically relatively easy to do). If it does show up in the BIOS, there's at least a chance that you can recover something.

Comment: how would i proceed if it shows up in BIOS or what are the diagnostics i would do?

Comment: The first thing is probably to check `dmesg` just to see if anything shows up. I would be surprised if the BIOS recognized the drive but the Linux kernel ignored it completely. This might give you some clue, at least.

Comment: ok thanks! I will get back to you if I get access to the HDD in the next couple days